# Extract attributes from a shapefile layer into polygons ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, clip, fields-attributes, extract

Apologies if I'm not going to explain myself too well, but I'm very new to this.

I have a layer with a series of separate polygons (squares) and another shapefile layer with different attributes and I want to clip that shapefile to my polygons so that the attributes are transferred to the polygons.

I have tried clipping, spatial joining and intersecting but none of them do what I need.

Is there a way to extract by shape using those polygons?[image]

Here is what the attribute table for the road looks like. Initially it was split in much many more polygons, I have dissolved them by NoiseClass already, but had to give the option to have more than one polygon per NoiseClass as the shapefile is too large and it would otherwise crash.

[image: road attribute table]
[image: squares attribute table]

Comment: But intersect do this, why is not a desired ouput?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! For some reason intersect is just creating a series of polygons for each attribute type with the shape of the square, while what I am try to get is a series of squares that have the attributes of the layer they overlap with. 
Where am I going wrong with this?

Comment: You want your output to be unaltered squares with attributes from the roads/rivers oer whatever they are?

Comment: Exactly BERA! 

Thanks for putting this in much better words than I could. 
(And yes, they are roads)

Comment: Each feature has their own attributes, I see 5 kinds at least. So, I don't know what you want or if it's possible

Comment: You should not work with shapefiles. Use copy features and convert into features in a file geodatabase and it will not crash or be to large. You want total area of each noise class as columns for each square?

Comment: I've added screenshots of both attribute tables.
What you said makes sense, but I am not sure how to use the Dissolve tool in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the square geometries intact and with an attribute table looking something like this:

```
PLAN_NO AREA_NOISECLASS_1   AREA_NOISECLASS_2   AREA_NOISECLASS_3       …
N12323  45645               42121               4542        
H324    21541               545                 24424       
…
```

You can try:

1. Intersect squares and roads, save output in a file geodatabase to get a shape area column
2. [Pivot table](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/pivot-table.htm) (Advanced license needed) with Intersect as input and with shape area as value field, noise class as pivot field and plan_no as input field
3. [Join](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-join.htm) pivot table back to the squares using plan_no as join field
4. Use Copy Features to save as new feature class

Not sure if this is what you want though.

Comment: Thank you ever so much for this! After quite a bit of tweaking it finally worked! You really saved my life here, I had been going absolutely crazy with this for weeks! :)

Answer (score 0):

As I understood from what you look for, you can use (Symmetric difference) tool.

For example: I have two shapefiles one (with 4 squares) and the other (with land use)

[image]

Then I will use symmetric difference:

[image]

And the output shape files something like this:
[image]

Is that what you look for? if not! can you draw on paper how you want your result to look like (small sketch), to give us  a better idea